# php post via html <a> tags

Tags: php, html

I have built a site using php and want to try keep it one page.. The site displays pictures and so far i have it making links from folders in a folder each folder contains images so what i want is to make a post/get tag in the url and when the page loads it uses this to get the images from that folder.

So I want to use the generated links to post to the same page with a value via self_post is this possible and if so how?

my get section is

```
if(empty($_post['foldername']))
{
   $directory = "portfolio/homepage/";

}
else if(isset($_post['foldername']))
{
   $foldername = $_post['foldername'];
   $directory = "portfolio/".$foldername."/";       
}
```

and my link is like this

```
echo '<li><a id="" class="" href="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'">'.$b.'<input type="hidden" name="foldername" value="'.$b.'" /></a></li>';
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't have an idea of what you're talking about, but you can't post using an anchor element. At most, you may need to make the anchor force a form to be submitted: `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('yourform').submit();">link</a>`

Comment: Thanks I get that now new to php and trying to keep a site page dynamic and not have to make multi pages..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with GET?

```
<a href="somefile.php?variable=value&anothervar=awesome">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make more sense as a comment? It's a suggestion, not an answer to the question?

Comment: In a way it is an answer, because it solves the problem. If the question is asking how to do something that's a bad idea, suggesting a good way to do it seems like a valid answer to me.

Comment: I went with this as it was simple to add and dont need to add forms! Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I just had a hard time assuming that the OP didn't realize they could just use GET

Comment: What's wrong with GET? Lots of reasons actually. It's not *useless*, but it's not *always* the best solution. For example, you might want to store page state independent of the URL (eg; so it can't be bookmarked). POST would be perfect in such a case.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make a POST request using a `<a>` tag would be to have it submit a form via javascript:

```
<form method="post" id="hidden_form" name="hidden_form" action="script.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="foldername" value="<?php echo $b ?>" />
</form>

...

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_form').submit(); return false">post me</a>
```

You can also update the values of the hidden element(s) from javascript as well so when you click a particular link, it sets one of the values to something specific to the link.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is doing it through JS. You can either send an AJAX request specifying POST, or you can create a hidden form and submit it. Here's an example

```
document.getElementById('my-link').onclick = function(){
    // Code to submit the hidden form or to send an AJAX request specifying POST
    return false; // to prevent the default behavior
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to do this with vanilla anchor tags.  You could establish click event handlers in javascript to submit an XHR request.  However, I have accomplished this in the past by using multiple form tags with a single submit entity (`<input type='submit'`, `<button type='submit'`, etc.).

Your forms would look like so:

```
<form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="foldername" value="YOURVALUEHERE">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like drew010 said if you absolutly need the POST method. Otherwise most single-page website uses things like index.php?a=1&b=2 where you can get "a" and "b" with $_GET["a"] ...

Comment: This would allow it to work without JS, it sounds like the OP needs POST because it's too much content for GET?